# Parseerror with Json and Jquery

Tags: jquery, json, parse-error

I have the following Json:

```
[{"label":"75001","value":"75001"},
{"label":"75002","value":"75002"},
{"label":"75003","value":"75003"},
{"label":"75004","value":"75004"},
{"label":"75005","value":"75005"},
{"label":"75006","value":"75006"},
{"label":"75007","value":"75007"},
{"label":"75008","value":"75008"},
{"label":"75009","value":"75009"}]
```

It causes a parseerror in JQuery.

I actually use the jquery.ui autocomplete control as follows:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery("#accountPostcode").autocomplete({
                source : function(request, response) {
                    var jqxhr = jQuery.ajax({
                        url : "utils/JSonPostcodesWithQueryParam",
                        dataType : "json"
                    }).fail(function() { 
                        console.log("error:");
                        console.log(jqxhr.statusText);
                    });
                },
                minLength : 2
            });
        });
```

I am not sure what I am getting wrong as my Json seems correct...

Any one has any clue?

EDIT:

Here is what generates the Json:

```
package com.bignibou.web.pages.utils;

import java.util.List;

import org.apache.tapestry5.EventConstants;
import org.apache.tapestry5.StreamResponse;
import org.apache.tapestry5.annotations.OnEvent;
import org.apache.tapestry5.annotations.RequestParameter;
import org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.annotations.Inject;
import org.apache.tapestry5.util.TextStreamResponse;

import com.bignibou.domain.utils.PostcodeJson;
import com.bignibou.service.AccountService;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class JSonPostcodesWithQueryParam {

    @Inject
    private AccountService service;

    @OnEvent(EventConstants.ACTIVATE)
    StreamResponse loadPostcodes(@RequestParameter(value = "term") String beginningOfPostcode) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        List<PostcodeJson> postcodes = service.loadPostcodes(beginningOfPostcode);
        return new TextStreamResponse("application/json","UTF-8", gson.toJson(postcodes));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't see anything wrong with your code other the fact that you never do anything with the results of your AJAX call. Here's a [full working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XtzCV/1/). I suspect that your server might somehow not return correct JSON which is the most likely cause of the error. You should make absolutely sure that the server responds with status code 200, sets `Content-Type` header to `application/json` and sends the exact JSON in the response body. Use FireBug or similar tool to analyse what exactly is sent over the wire during this AJAX request.

Also you don't seem to ever be sending the term request parameter. Try like this:

```
jQuery('#accountPostcode').autocomplete({
    source : function(request, response) {
        var jqxhr = jQuery.ajax({
            url : 'utils/JSonPostcodesWithQueryParam',
            data: { term: request.term },
            dataType : 'json'
        }).fail(function() {
            console.log('error:');
            console.log(jqxhr.statusText);
        }).success(function(data) {
            response(data);
        });
    },
    minLength : 2
});
```

Comment: Darin. Thanks a lot for the demo. I do spot a problem using the network tool of Chrome. the content type is set to "text/html". It is odd because I did specify   `TextStreamResponse("application/json","UTF-8", gson.toJson(postcodes)); `

Comment: @balteo, what about the contents of the response? Is it JSON actually? I suspect that the server set it to text/html because there was an error on the server and it rendered an error page. The fact that you set `dataType: 'json'` means that jQuery ignores the server Content-Type header and assumes JSON. But if the server doesn't send correct JSON in the response it won't work. So fix your server side code.

Comment: Found the problem!! It was due to a wrongly specified url: `url : 'utils/JSonPostcodesWithQueryParam',` Basic mistake on my part!! Thanks all!! It actually resolved to the home page of my app...

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your server is setting the header response to `application/json`. This can sometimes cause html to be parsed in the response depending on your backend.

Comment: Do you this parseerror might be due to the square brackets enclosing the json data?

Comment: Square brackets only says its an array. There's nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using Java but I was getting a similar parse error attempting to decode your JSON with PHP.  I had to manipulate your JSON to this to parse it properly:

```
{
    "key": {
        "0": {"label": "75001", "value": "75001"},
        "1": {"label": "75002", "value": "75002"},
        "2": {"label": "75003", "value": "75003"},
        "3": {"label": "75004", "value": "75004"},
        "4": {"label": "75005", "value": "75005"},
        "5": {"label": "75006", "value": "75006"},
        "6": {"label": "75007", "value": "75007"},
        "7": {"label": "75008", "value": "75008"},
        "8": {"label": "75009", "value": "75009"}
    }
}
```

I attempted to get it to parse without having to define the inner, numerical keys however I was still getting a parse error.  Hope this helps.